# StringTemplate don't replace non-matched patterns

Tags: java, template-engine, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

suppose I have a template

```
"{man} likes to do {do}"
```

I create the engine

```
 ST engine = new ST(template, '{', '}');
```

The result with `do` set to `sports` and no `man` in the model is:

```
"likes to do sports"
```

but I'd prefer it to stay unresolved, that is

```
"{man} likes to do sports"
```

Can this be done in StringTemplate 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if-else` construct in the template file to check if a parameter to the template is provided.

Example: `{if (man)}{man}{else}\{man\}{endif}`, I am not sure if this is the correct way to escape delimiters though.

Comment: No no, i need this behavior by default set e.g. at `ST` construction time